# pytest import fails with test directory – "no module found named ..."

Tags: python, pytest

I am a newbie with pytests, read through docs, but that did not help. So asking here.

My project structure:

```
├─ lexor
  ├─ __init__.py
  ├─ lexor
  │  ├─ __init__.py
  │  └─ MyClass.py
  ├─ lib
  └─ tests
     ├─ __init__.py
     └─ test_MyTest.py
```

Code in `test_MyTest.py`

```
from lexor.MyClass import MyClass

class test_MyTest:
   def test1(self):
      assert True
```

Running `pytest` from outer `lexor` directory yields an error:
 `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lexor.MyClass'`

I know there is something simple I am missing.. Please help.

Comment: Try to remove the `__init__.py` from the top most lexor directory - it should be there, it might be confusing python to look `MyClass` there instead in the inner folder.

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. Can you make an answer out of it, so I could mark it the solution please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `__init__.py` in the root directory - it confuses python which tries to look for `MyClass` in the root directory instead of the subdirectory.

Just remove this file:

```
├─ lexor
  ├─ __init__.py   <-- delete me
  ├─ lexor
  │  ├─ __init__.py
  │  └─ MyClass.py
  ├─ lib
  └─ tests
     ├─ __init__.py
     └─ test_MyTest.py
```